# how can i fetch only last order id placed in my magento2 store in api?

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

Hi i have a an api file for fetching orders coming in my magento2 store , this is the code below which is successfully fetching my order number 66 from database , **`

> **i wants to know how can i fetch only last order placed in my list ?**

`** so that i can get all upcoming latest orders.

---

```
<?php
$adminUrl='http://host.pk/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "user11", "password" => "pass11");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);   

//Use above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 

$requestUrl='http://host.pk/index.php/rest/V1/orders/66';


$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: I have added a **DESC** sort order for order **created_at** attribute. Which gives the last created order.

```
<?php
$adminUrl='http://host.pk/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "user11", "password" => "pass11");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);   

//Use above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 

$requestUrl='http://host.pk/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC';


$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: its not returning any single record , blank page

Comment: i fetch last order using this way , please check my new question , now i wants last order status , please help me in sql https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215935/how-to-get-status-of-last-order-id-in-magento2-sql-query